# How do I pass the 'default' argument in a Power BI call to a date parameter in a table-valued user-defined function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have a table-valued user-defined function in SQL Server that accepts a date parameter.

For example:

```
create function [dbo].[udfGetSomeDay]
(   
     @TheDay date = '1/1/2025'
)
returns table 
as
return 
(
    select @TheDay as TheReturnedDay
)
```

In SSMS, I can use the default parameter like this:

```
select * from [dbo].[udfGetSomeDay](default)
```

...which returns:
[image: SSMS Result]

But when I call that same function, in the same way, from Power BI, I get:
[image]

Comment: create another function that has no parameters which calls your function with default

Comment: @siggemannen, that's clever, and I will probably end up doing just that but hoping for a solution that doesn't require the creation of additional functions. I'm going to let this question simmer a bit.